# How to dynamically assign a name and type to unknown object property in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using Shopify's rest client for node and its request and response look something like this:

- request

```js
client.get({
  path: 'orders/count.json',
  query: { fulfillment_status: 'unfulfilled' }
})
```

- If there's an error:

```json
{
  "errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access...",
  "code": 2342,
  "statusText": "Authentication Error",
  "Headers": "..."
}
```

- If there's no error:

```json
{
  "body": { "count": 8 },
  "code": 2342,
  "statusText": "Authentication Error",
  "Headers": "..."
}
```

I'd like to add some boilerplate over this client library so that I can get the typings of the response. This is what I'm trying to do but it's not working too well:

```js
const customClient = {

  get: async <T, K extends string>(params: GetRequestParams) => {
      const response = (await client.get(params));
      if (response.body.errors) return { errors: response.body.errors };
      // somehow index it. obviously not with the type declaration???
      return { [K]: response.body[K] as T };
    },

}
```

With the hopes that I can use it as.

```js
const { count, error } = customClient.get<number, "count">({ ... });
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have an entire file of the Shopify API types that I would like to leverage. A solution to this would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible implementation can look like this:

```
const customClient = {
  get: async <T, K extends string>(params: GetRequestParams): 
      Promise<Partial<Record<K, T> & { errors: string }>> => 
    {
      const response = (await client.get(params));
      if (response.body.errors) return { errors: response.body.errors } as any;

      return { 
        [Object.keys(response)[0]]: response[Object.keys(response)[0]] 
      } as any
    },
}
```

As you correctly noted, we can't use the TypeScript generic types when constructing the returning object. We need to use JavaScript features instead. In this case I just took the first key of the `response` and used it for the key of the returning object as well as to index the `response` object.

The return type of the function is a `Promise` consisting of both a `Record` with `K` and `T` as keys and values and the error type. I used `Partial` here since they are not both required.

Destructing the response leads to the correct types now:

```
async function main(){
  const { count, errors } = await customClient.get<number, "count">({} as any);
  // count: number | undefined
  // errors: string | undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwEqoI4FdUDOMACgIZSkgFwC%20cAZlBCHAEQACBAFhGMPQE8A9N178BAWlJ9WAWABQCgMYQAdkThKANsFSr4AXkQK4cAOboAXHAAUYcpQLW0mHPiJkKVAJTXSqgTgDAD5EGgVwxXkVdXglXCJmAGEdPUNjeVMLGD8CAVUlOAAeABUAGjgAaThUAA8YPQATaiIoYFUzYLsHKmd0LDxCEh6CXzgTU0niJhBgAlQizxhgUi0irBUoRqLKipLQgDJEGqgmKCc4VvazWmDQkPHMyYQJyc01DShCSHVUINtSAB3UjAOKpfQAOmy3S8o28AG5XpN%20LYvgQfvMIQAjCCNAQQ1CnaCjOBfGC4KCqY6Es4XNEY1DY3H4mnE2hwUjUfwCRFRN6mMkUqlIJFvADaAHksQArVBKGAQgDWqAEBBs9I%20qG8YoADABdPXWDW-SUyuUK5Wq9XfTXa-V6x789mcjkBJE0MoRBQKTn5Qr0XAFZZqOAgEGqGzeF5PGIaJAqQMwCqs87soxAkFxBIwZLghXZIqqXAgLGEiqsBP6VhdBB0F3chERIA)